# What does lower bound maximization mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

I was reading about the Expectation Maximization algorithm for parameters in a statistical model.

In the notes that I'm reading it says that EM is used for lower bound maximization.

What does this mean?

Comment: maximizes a lower bound on the marginal likelihood. Google variational Bayes.